# Is "transferring data" used when talking about people?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary, colloquial-language

I know that "data" and "transfer" are used when talking about technology and things like that. My question is when talking about people learning new things, can I use the words "data" and "transfer" as well? 
For example in the following sentence:

> Data is transferred to/among new students from their teachers.

Is that usage correct? Is there a more colloquial way of saying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally speak of information and knowledge in the teacher-student relationship, rather than data.

The verbs used to express that sharing of information can be

**share**

**pass**

**pass down**

**impart**

among others.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to *people*, the common term is **knowledge transfer**.

From [Training Industry](https://trainingindustry.com/wiki/content-development/knowledge-transfer/):

> Knowledge transfer is the process by which experienced employees share or distribute their knowledge, skills and behaviors to the employees replacing them . . .
>
> A variety of tools and methods are employed to accomplish successful knowledge transfer, according to research. Among them are peer-to-peer and team training activities such as mentor networks, coaching, and work shadowing. Other popular methods include technology-based activities such as video captured presentations, social and collaborative tools such as chat, forum, intranet blog postings; and mobile devices.

It is also used in the context of academic learning.

From the [University of Cambridge](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/what-is-knowledge-transfer):

> It’s all about the transfer of tangible and intellectual property, expertise, learning and skills between academia and the non-academic community.

---

I had also thought of **information transfer**. However, even though Google Books NGram Viewer [shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knowledge%20transfer%2C%20information%20transfer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cknowledge%20transfer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinformation%20transfer%3B%2Cc0) it's a more commonly used phrase, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_transfer) indicates it's mostly used in a technical sense:

> In telecommunications, information transfer is the process of moving messages containing user information from a source to a sink via a Communication channel. In this sense, information transfer is equivalent to data transmission which highlights more practical, technical aspects.
>
> The information transfer rate may or may not be equal to the transmission modulation rate.
>
> Bidirectional information transfer is called information exchange.
>
> **Non-technical meaning**
>
> In a non-technical context, information transfer is sometimes used to signify knowledge transfer or teaching.